# IPython Notebook works after computer wakes

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have some complicated iterative work in my IPython Notebook and I have no time to complete calculations at university. If I close notebook, take it home and open, it will wake and I see that kernel did not die. So, if I wait will it finish? If it is true, is it safe for computed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Kernel is not running in browser, browser is just the enviroment where you can interactive with the kernel at remote (where you started jupyter).